# php strftime French characters

Tags: php

I'm working on a site where the user can switch between English and French. To output the date of posts.

If the user chooses French I use:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fra_fra');
```

Then to output the date I use:

```
strftime('%d %B %Y', strtotime($post->post_date));
```

I have my charset at utf-8 with:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

The problem I have is characters like **û** and others with accents just display as the black diamonds with question marks in.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Have you this issue in page content in general or in dates only?

Comment: It was only occurring in the dates. Using utf8_enocde has fixed this

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This seems to be a problem / bug with the `strftime` function.

You can solve it using:

```
$date_string = utf8_encode(strftime('%d %B %Y', strtotime($post->post_date)));
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you.

Comment: Perfect ! Fixed my issue too.
Had an accent in the date format and had to add it as an UTF8 code.

Had to change :
`%e %B %Y à%kh%M`
to : 
`%e %B %Y &agrave; %kh%M`

Comment: Problem is, `utf8_encode` on a string that's already in `utf-8` will garble the accents _even more_. Additionally, `mb_detect_encoding` reported `F�vrier` (which should read `Février`) as being `utf-8` already.

Comment: @RémiBreton Actually if you check it with the `$strict` parameter set to `true`, it works: `mb_detect_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', true)` will return `true` if `$str` is UTF-8 (Février) and `false` if not (F�vrier).

Comment: Choosing a UTF-8 locale is the better way as many other comments show it (fr_FR.UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks F2000! Jeroen´s solution doesnt work for me but yours yes.

Answer (score 16):

The Content-Type header needs to set the code page to UTF-8.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Since you can't change the header once you've output anything to the page with **echo** or **print** make sure you set it early in the page.

The ASCII code page is fully contained in UTF-8 not vice-versa.

Replace the **UTF-8** header with the **ASCII** one and you'll see what happens when the characters aren't included in the current code page.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
//header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ASCII');

$myDate = "Feb 23, 2011";

$locale = 'fr_FR.UTF-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
echo strftime('%d %B %Y', strtotime($myDate));  

$locale = 'en_US.UTF-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
echo strftime('%d %B %Y', strtotime($myDate));
?>
```

Comment: `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF8');`, and not just `'fr_FR'`, fixed it for me.

Answer (score 14):

Locales come in different encodings! You are advertising your site as using UTF-8, but `strftime` does not return a UTF-8 encoded string, because the locale you chose is not a UTF-8 locale. Check your system what locales you have, e.g.:

```
$ locale -a | grep fr_FR
fr_FR
fr_FR.ISO8859-1
fr_FR.ISO8859-15
fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Then choose the UTF-8 variant of your locale, e.g.:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8');
```

If you do not have a UTF-8 variant of your locale available, either consult the help system of your OS how to install it, or do an encoding conversion in PHP.

Comment: What about Windows OS ?

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul');
    setlocale(LC_TIME,"turkish");
    echo date("d.m.Y").' - '.iconv("ISO-8859-9","UTF-8",strftime('%A'));
?>
```

// 11.06.2015 - Perşembe

Answer (score 4):

If you display your page with utf8 encoding, you want to get utf8 out of strftime.

If php's charset is utf8, then you're cooking. If not, you can  :

- `utf8_encode()` the output of strftime.
- append `'.utf8'` to your locale statement if this locale is installed on your system, as in `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.utf8')`
- change php's default charset, by putting the line `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`  in your `php.ini` or your `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

```
utf8_encode(strftime('%e %B %Y', $this->createDate->getTimestamp()))
```

doesn't work for me

```
    class DateUtil
    {
    const FORMAT_DAY_OF_WEEK        = '%A';
    const FORMAT_HUMANY             = '%e %B %Y';

    private static $monthInGenitiveCase = [
        '01' => 'января',
        '02' => 'февраля',
        '03' => 'марта',
        '04' => 'апреля',
        '05' => 'мая',
        '06' => 'июня',
        '07' => 'июля',
        '08' => 'августа',
        '09' => 'сентября',
        '10' => 'октября',
        '11' => 'ноября',
        '12' => 'декабря'
    ];

    public static function dow(DateTime $date)
    {
        return self::format($date, self::FORMAT_DAY_OF_WEEK);
    }

    public static function humany(DateTime $date)
    {
        return self::format($date, '%e ') .self::$monthInGenitiveCase[self::format($date, '%m')] .self::format($date, ' %Y');
    }

    public static function format(DateTime $date, $format)
    {
        return strftime($format, $date->getTimestamp());
    }

}
```

Usage

```
DateUtil::humany($this->createDate)
```

Ofcourse it works only for one language, but in some cases it's enough.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this on header?

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Many functions about string that are not binary safe, have an mb_xxxx equivalent. So consider also this  http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: With utf-8 one letter is two bytes. Usually the diamond character with question mark means the one byte of the two of a character.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue but `header()`, `utf8_encode()` & `setlocale()` weren't working and we did not know the actual encoding. This is how we solved it (if it helps anyone) :

```
// $date_start is a DateTime instance
$month = strftime("%b", $date_start->getTimestamp());

// The default value for the 3rd argument is FALSE, this can cause issues
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($month, 'auto', true);

// We can now correctly convert the string to UTF-8
$converted = mb_convert_encoding($month, 'UTF-8', $encoding);
```

**Note:** [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) expects to encode from a *ISO-8859-1* encoded string only.

**Manual:**

- [DateTime::getTimestamp()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php)
- [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)
- [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the function:

`echo utf8_encode(strftime('%d %B %Y', strtotime($post->post_date)))`