# French characters not displaying properly STRFTIME

Tags: php, html, meta

I've been outputting my date as `strftime` depending on the localization chose by the user.  The language in question is French and the dates are displaying like this: `jeudi 08 ao�t 2013`

It doesn't recognize any of the special characters. However, this **only** happens when I'm trying to output a date using `strftime`. Everything else is displaying perfect.

Here is my setup:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

setlocale (LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.utf8','fra'); // depending on the language chose
```

Any ideas on what's causing this issue?

Comment: Are you sure the page is being rendered by the browser in the correct encoding? What happens when you wrap the strftime() result in utf8_encode()? You should also ensure that locale (fr_FR.utf8) exists on the server.

Comment: Yea...wrapping it fixed the problem, but now I need to get the page to render in like this because I can't just simply wrap the `strftime`  function with this. hmmm.

Comment: Are you sure that locale exists on your server? Depending on the OS/Distro they can have varying names. Running "locale -a" for example will give you the available locales on a Linux box.

Comment: Did you save the .php script file in "UTF-8 without BOM"?

Comment: Yes, by default all my file are saved as such: `C(Canonical Decomposition, followed by Canonical Composition)`  and `Include Unicode Signature (BOM)` is always checked off.

Comment: Duplicate with an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8995320/1352471