# Passing array containing accents from Laravel to vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to send an array of object from Laravel to Vue.js data. This code only works when `App::isLocale('fr') === false` I mean without accent.

Do there is another way to pass an array to vue.js ?

**controller**

```
public function dashboard($userToken)
{
    $data = [];
    $data['projects'] = $this->user->listprojects($userToken);

    if (App::isLocale('fr')) {
        setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
    } else {
        setlocale(LC_TIME, "en_US");
    }

    foreach ($data['projects'] as $project) {
        $project->date = strftime('%d %B %Y - %H:%M',$project->date) ;
    }
    return view('dashboard',$data);
}
```

**model**

```
public function listprojects($userToken){
    $projects = DB::table('projects')
        ->select('project_name as name', 
                'project_token as token',
        ->where('project_user_id', $userToken)
        ->orderBy('project_date_modif', 'desc')
        ->get();
    return $projects;
}
```

**view**

```
<script>
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        projects: <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($projects) ?>
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from the function `strftime` which have some bugs according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995320/3200799). So I changed the controller like that :

```
public function dashboard($userToken)
{
    $data = [];
    $data['projects'] = $this->user->listprojects($userToken);

    if (App::isLocale('fr')) {
        setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
    } else {
        setlocale(LC_TIME, "en_US");
    }

    foreach ($data['projects'] as $project) {
        $project->date = utf8_encode(strftime('%d %B %Y - %H:%M',$project->date) );
    }
    return view('dashboard',compact("data"));
}
```

And the view like @Babak suggested :

```
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            presentations: <?php echo(json_encode($data['projects'])) ?>
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

convert your array to json like this

```
return view('dashboard',compact("data"));
```

and then in Vue.js convert it back.

Comment: return an error `array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array`

Comment: The view keep return `Undefined variable: projects`

Comment: In view change $projects to $data